# OBD II Command to get distance

Tags: java, android, obd-ii

I am trying to get distance the user has passed from the last time that the codes cleared

"Distance traveled since codes cleared"
[http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OBD-II_PIDs](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OBD-II_PIDs#Mode_01)

But I am not getting any data. 
I am using this open source library. 
https://github.com/pires/android-obd-reader
and I am constructing the Command with this parameter

```
public ObdKMCommand() {
    super("01 31");
}
```

what am I missing ?

Comment: I've not used your linked library, but (a) Why `01`? (b) does it need the number in decimal (that `31` is a hex code)?

Comment: I have looked at the other command and I am the on the docs on wiki and I think that it shouldn't be hex.

Comment: Do you get some data if you send 010D?

Comment: Not sure I have to check agin. It really hard to work when you have to do the debugging in your car.

Comment: You can try to download OBDSim. A bit hard to setup, but it works great when you've done it. http://icculus.org/obdgpslogger/obdsim.html

Comment: By the way, I can't find the ObdKMCommand in that repository.

Comment: @EricSmekens you are right i didn't push it because it not working
here is the bug in the right repository 
[link](https://github.com/pires/obd-java-api/issues/2)

Comment: the answer is in that link the full command code is here https://github.com/pires/obd-java-api/commit/471e299fb8c77eaef630b81f23b08eb5841c702f
[github issue ](https://github.com/pires/obd-java-api/issues/2)

Answer (score 0):

Try sending this kind of command to your obd device – 
`0131\r` (i.e. `MM PP\r` format and don't forget to append `\r` at the end of your command). OBD device identifies the end of command request by `\r`. So I am getting proper response while sending this command pattern and receiving 2 bytes response as expected.